# Button is too near with the previous line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to move my "Submit form" a little bit down. i have tried a lot but the problem doesn't seems to go away.....

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-down">Submit form</button>
</div>
```

Button is too near with the other line:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) Please see [mcve] + [ask]. You provided the button but what exactly is above it can make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-down">Submit form</button> 
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra class to your button to avoid overriding bootstrap CSS and then simply add something like so

your HTML become :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-down mybutton">Submit form</button> 
                   </div>
```

suggested CSS

```
.mybutton {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14159/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query (form-group will add space itself on smaller viewports) and a custom class on the form-group div to add margin to the top.

See Snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .lg-group {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group lg-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit form</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```